# Determining whether iOS application was launched via Siri

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, siri

I've been looking forever, but haven't found… Do you know if there's a way to
determine whether my iOS app was launched by Siri or by the user tapping the app icon?

I need to know because I want to automate a startup action only when my app is
launched from Siri.

I was thinking that maybe **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** or
some other API would allow my app to know how it was launched, but that doesn't
seem to be the case (or I just missed it).

Any idea if there's some trick available that I could use until Apple publishes
some official/public Siri API ?

Comment: i don't think siri is public within API form

Comment: we have the same question if the application would know if it was started by siri or through a click on the app icon

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can suggest is to check the launchOption dictionary passed in as part of `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

There is one key that claims to list the name of the application that requested your apps launch and maybe Siri would be listed:

From the apple doc located [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW18):

`UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey`

> The presence of this key identifies the app that requested the launch of your app. The value of this key is an NSString object that represents the bundle ID of the app that made the request.
>   This key is also used to access the same value in the userInfo dictionary of the notification named UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification.
>   Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
>   Declared in UIApplication.h.

Comment: When I launch the app from SIRI neither  application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions nor application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions method is called.

Comment: These delegate functions are called when I launch my app with Siri. However, the launch options parameter is nil.

Answer (score 0):

When I launch from Siri, application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called. However, my launchOptions dictionary is empty.  If I launch the app using a URL scheme, my launchOptions dictionary has the appropriate keys.  At this time, it doesn't look like it's possible to know if the app was launched from Siri

Answer (score 0):

List of launch options provided by apple

`let UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey: String
let UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey: String
let UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey: String
let UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey: String
let UIApplicationLaunchOptionsAnnotationKey: String
let UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey: String
let UIApplicationLaunchOptionsNewsstandDownloadsKey: String
let UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey: String
let UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothPeripheralsKey: String
let UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey: String
let UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey: String
let UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityTypeKey: String`

Here's the link to apple's documentation  [Launch Options Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Launch_Options_Keys).
Here's the link to Quora regarding official/public Siri API [Quora Link](https://www.quora.com/What-do-application-developers-need-to-know-about-Siri-to-interface-with-it)